# When we pass by reference, why do we put a variable instead of address(pointer), when calling the function?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

```
void ChangeValueByReference(int &x)
{
    x = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    ChangeValueByReference(a);
    cout << a;
}
```

Why don't we put `ChangeValueByReference(&a);` when calling that function in main()?

Because while defining the function, we said that we will be passing a pointer `void ChangeValueByReference(int &x){...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the ampersand has two different meanings, when used in different places (declaration / statement).

```
void MyFn(Type & a);
```

Here & serves as "a reference to" modifier.

```
Type * pA = &a;
```

Here & serves as "get a pointer of" operator. Notice that if you have variable `a` of type `Type`, `&a` returns `Type *` (a pointer to `Type`).

Compiler automatically gets a reference to variable, when you pass it to the function. So you can simply call:

```
ChangeValueByReference(someVariable);
```

And compiler will know, that it has to get a reference to someVariable.

Comment: *"get a pointer of" operator* is often called the "address operator" or the ["address-of operator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64sa8b1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

We did not say that we'll be passing a pointer. We said that we will give a reference. A reference to a variable might internally be handled like a pointer *but* it is no pointer. A pointer can be 0 - a reference not.